# Building gearman type application using RabbitMQ

Tags: php, messaging, rabbitmq, gearman

I'm looking for a general overview of best practice to implement a "job allocation" system like Gearman using RabbitMQ messaging system.

So basically I'd have something reading the queue and forking? instances to run a job?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend taking a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) which does something like this. Google for Celery and RabbitMQ to get some links, or start [here](http://delicious.com/alexisrichardson/rabbitmq+celery).